# Angular Material matInput text is partially hidden while typing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 5 with the Material design. I found very weird display issue with matInput where the text (like g) is partially hidden in edit mode. Interestingly this behavior is present in Angular Material sample as well See here: [Angular Material Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bnjxqqjkykd/)

[image: My application screen capture]

Any help to fix this issue?

Issue found on MacOS (Macbook Pro) and is reproducible on both chrome and safari.

Comment: It's Angular, **not** AngularJS. By the way, you should try reporting this issue at the source code: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues

Comment: Sure i will do this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the line height to the element. Use `::ng-deep` if you add styles to pseudo classes.

```css
  .mat-input-element {
    line-height: normal !important;
  }
```